# Distributed AG to migrate from SS2016 to SS2019

Tags: sql-server, distributed-availability-groups

I am planning on migrating from SQL Server 2016 AG1 running on WSFC 2012 to SQL Server 2019 AG2 running on WSFC 2022.
I want to use using Distributed AG to minimize downtime.

is this scenario without much pain? I need to know if I should pursue it and what obstacles lie out there.

A follow up question: if after failover to the new AG2, what are the steps to configure the SQL Server 2016 to receive data from SQL Server 2019? Of course, at some point after migration, I will be dropping the DAG.

Answer (score 1):

> is this scenario without much pain?

Creating and using Distributed AGs aren't painful, in my opinion. Whether or not this all works with your infrastructure and specific database needs is unknown, nor is it known how easy or hard it may be for you. This is subjective per environment.

> A follow up question: if after failover to the new AG2, what are the steps to configure the SQL Server 2016 to receive data from SQL Server 2019?

You can't, you can only go up in version. Once the failover to 2019 occurs, you can't go back to 2016. Any new information put into 2019 will not flow back and thus if you choose to go back to 2016, you'll need to figure out a way to sync these.

Comment: thank you, Sean.

SQL Server infrastructure is various types of EC2 machines, some of them very large, and nothing on-prem. We have over 20 Always On Availability Groups on WSFC clusters that host over 500 databases, with a total of 35 TB.
We have been running the AGs for over 2 years, and both the the operations and engineering side are well versed in them 
We want to migrate to SS2019, and we are starting that process. Team members mentioned Distributed AG, but our team has no actual experience. And, that's why is posted my question. 

Thank you for answering the second question.

Comment: If you're very familiar with regular AGs, then distributed are essentially AGs that work on and hold other AGs :)